# ASP.NET MVC3 Copy file to Shared Mapped Drive - Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, permissions

Currently I am getting this error when trying to copy a local file over to a shared network drive.
 `Access to the path '\\vlanxxxx\Vlanxxx\VT\12345.pdf' is denied'`

Background Information

- Running ASP.NET MVC3, Windows Server 2008 R2
- In `IIS->Application Pools` my Application has the correct permission to access the shared drive
- I have tried copying the file from a local folder to local folder and it worked successfully.
   i.e `C:\log\12345.pdf -> C:\test\12345.pdf`

**Purpose:** My overall purpose is to copy a file in my local server to a shared mapped network drive. 
**Q:** Is this actually possible when using ASP.NET, is there any networked shared drive limitations when using this technology?

**Code for copying the file over** (I am pretty sure the code is fine, but here is the code incase)

```
String path = @"C:\log\12345.pdf";
String dest_path = @"\\vlanxxxx\Vlanxxx\VT\12345.pdf";
File.Copy(path, Path.Combine(dest_path, Path.GetFileName(path)));
```

Thank you for the help and assistance, I appreciate your time! Please let me know if there is any misunderstanding in the question. I will try to edit and clarify as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS, try to give write permission to the users `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSR` in that destination path / folder.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but what exactly do you mean, and how do you do this?

Comment: https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a443/how-to-give-write-access-to-files-for-iusr.aspx is this what you mean?

Comment: Wow is a shared network drive sorry, but by the way, give permissions to this user in that folder : right click (folder)/Security tab/ Add / search IUSR and IIS_IUSR / Check Names / Ok / and set permissions in both users. I hope this help :-)

Comment: @AustinTruong Exactly but try with IIS_IUSR user too. IIS need permissions to write in your location.